# Stale Element Reference error using protractor

Tags: javascript, protractor

The scenario I am trying is when I have multiple links in the modal and clicking on each link a description opens up in the same modal. The first click works fine, but when it goes back to the list of links, it doesn't click on the second link in a for loop, and gives the following error:

```
Failed: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
(Session info: chrome=66.0.3359.139)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.37.544315 (730aa6a5fdba159ac9f4c1e8cbc59bf1b5ce12b7),platform=Windows NT 10.0.16299 x86_64)
```

The code I have written is:

```
this.new = function () {
element(by.xpath('')).click();
browser.sleep(5000);
browser.switchTo().defaultContent();

element.all(by.xpath('')).then(function(total){

length=total.length;

element.all(by.xpath('linkname')).then(function(ann){ 

for(i=0;i<length;i++)
{ 
ann[i].click();
browser.sleep(2000);
element(by.id("back")).click();
browser.sleep(2000);

}
}); 
});

};
```

Any advice would be welcomed. Thanks

Comment: You have to find the link in for loop again from the page after you back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
browser.switchTo().defaultContent();

element.all(by.xpath('linkname')).count().then(function(count) {

    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {

        (function(index) {
            // find the link again after back
            element.all(by.xpath('linkname')).get(index).click(); //index is the current element
            browser.sleep(2000);
            element(by.id("back")).click();
            browser.sleep(2000);
        })(i);

    }

});
```